# How to close the autocomplete dropdown of jquery-textcomplete programmatically?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I added a autocompletion to an input field with [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/). In some cases, I want to close it programmatically without losing focus on the text field.

How can you close the dropdown in code?

Answer (score 1):

*This is a workaround, as the API currently does not support this feature.*

**jquery-textcomplete** stores its information in the data attribute `textComplete`. You can close the dropdown by calling it's deactivate function like this:

```
yourAutocompleteField.data("textComplete").dropdown.deactivate();
```